# Using zkoss, why my Spring DAO still null even though I already setup it in the Spring config XML?

Tags: zk

I am using ZK to try to call Spring Manager/DAO from the existing spring JAR project. I already use this variable resolver in the zul file:

```
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<zk>
<window border="normal" width="400px" style="padding-top:20px;padding-left:20px;" title="Species Editor" apply="org.openforis.specieseditor.NewSpecies">
```

And able to call in the Java class `NewSpecies.java` this way :

```
    SpeciesManager speciesManager = (SpeciesManager) SpringUtil.getBean("speciesManager");      
    List<TaxonOccurrence> speciesList = speciesManager.findByScientificName(taxonomy, species, 1);
```

The problem is, inside this `SpeciesManager.java` there is a call to other DAO, e.g `taxonDao`, which create a `Null Pointer Exception`. And I really clueless of how this exception occur. Any help? I already add this `taxonDao` inside my spring config xml also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `apply="org.openforis.specieseditor.NewSpecies"` on your root component which means ZK will instantiate your composer instance and then Spring has no chance to inject the dependency as composer is not a Spring managed bean here. You can inject Spring dependencies in your composer by extending from SelectorComposer and VariableResolver annotation as shown below

```
@VariableResolver(org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver.class)
public class RegistrationSpringComposer extends SelectorComposer<Component> {

    @WireVariable
    private RegistrationDao registrationDao;

    @Listen("onClick = #submitButton")
    public void submit(){
        // omit irrelevant code for brevity
        registrationDao.add(newUser);
    }
}
```

OR
You can make your current `NewSpecies` into a Spring managed bean and use EL expression like `apply="${newSpecies}"` to let Spring handle the lifecycle of NewSpecies bean (Note: make sure NewSpecies has prototype scope)

Comment: Thanks! I already did all that you suggest here, now I can call `registrationDao`, but because inside `registrationDao` there is a call to another Dao, that call create `null pointer exception`. Any clue here?

Comment: I haven't use zk-spring here. Do I have to use it?

Comment: Hi, I opt your answer as accepted answer because your answer is close to what it really is. I just have to also add the `<context:component-scan  base-package="org.openforis.collect.manager,org.openforis.collect.persistence,org.openforis.collect.security">
 </context:component-scan>` which is all the packages that my beans reside. Thanks

And I don't have to use zkspring

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I assumed NPE was for your bean inside `NewSpecies`